# Repository Interface naming convention

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

If I declare a controller with dependency injection (interface to repository), what is the general naming convention for the repository?

Does the industry generally prefer,

```
productrepository

_productRepository

_ProductRepository?
```

Started programming, trying to learn

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{

    public ElectronicsContext _context;
    public IProductRepository<Product> _ProductRepository;
```

Comment: _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise_ Please avoid asking questions that are primary-opinion based, they are off-topic on Stack overflow. Read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to find out what kind of questions are on-topic

Comment: The .NET industry is moving out of the dated repository pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It suggests `ProductRepository`:

```
public IProductRepository<Product> ProductRepository;
```

Comment: that's what I saw from Resharper, which brought this question up, all the other resources are using _smallercase, etc, _productRepository

Comment: In C# there is a convention used by some people that underscore is used for private members.

Comment: ok so seems like industry standard is resharper, will use that, thanks-

Comment: @TVLamp Since your `ProductRepository` is public, you don't need to use underscore for it. The underscore is usually used for private members, as Krzysztof Błażełek already stated.

Comment: ok, changed it to private, Resharper just makes it lower case, does not do underscore, thanks-

Comment: @KrzysztofBłażełek: Just to be clear, there are no such **official guidelines** about the underscore. Microsoft has some [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) (which would be closes to official), but this generally only apply for public API (public/protected properties, classes etc.) and not for private members since they are never visible in the public API.

Comment: As such there are no official guidelines for private fields and members and each team decides for themselves which to use and which not. The underscore comes historically due to the bad highlighting and autocompetition support in early times of fields and local variables, so the underscore made it easier to spot that its private though its added-value is not that much with modern days IDEs

Comment: @S.Akbari It's an ASP.NET Controller, which should not have any kind of public property/field. Public fields are also recommended **against**. Sorry but I had to downvote. It doesn't matter how you name something that's wrong from the beginning

Comment: @TVLamp ReSharper is not "an industry standard", it's a paid tool that some programmers use.